# Can't get the HTTPS response using Volley

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-volley

I've been trying to learn about Volley and hence I made a simple app which has a connect button and when the button is pressed it displays the response as a TOAST but when I press the button I cannot neither of the TOAST messages(response TOAST and error TOAST)

Here's the kotlin code:

```
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.L
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/f2721dfa-df49-4c27-b1a3-4929b6b75de1"
    private var RQ  : RequestQueue? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.con_buttom)
        button.setOnClickListener {sendrequest()}


    }

    fun sendrequest()
    {
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            {response ->  Onresponse(response)},
            {Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Couldn't Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})

        RQ?.add(stringRequest)
    }

    fun Onresponse(response : String)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response :" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

Here's the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/con_buttom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the URL link : https://run.mocky.io/v3/f2721dfa-df49-4c27-b1a3-4929b6b75de1

Please help me. I'm just a beginner
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 RQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
```

After

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

In your `onCreate` method.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    RQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.con_buttom)
    button.setOnClickListener { sendrequest() }
}
```

It's not working because your RQ is null

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have a doubt. From my understanding Request Queue helps in storing certain requests in the cache so that retrieving the request becomes way faster ..Even if I initialize it will NULL it shouldn't make any difference just  that it would be slower because we're not storing the requests in the Request Queue...

Comment: No, RequestQueue's only responsibility is not just caching, caching is one of the part, its main responsibility to execute the requests you have created. if it's null your request will not be processed at all.
if you want to read more about caching in volley read this https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue